# How to read $1_{\beta_k(t)}(j)$?

Tags: probability, notation

In my work, I came across the following notation:
\begin{equation}
  1_{\beta_k(t)}(j) \triangleq \begin{cases}
    1, &  {\beta_k(t)} = j \\
    0, & {\beta_k(t)} \neq j
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $t = \{1,...,T\}$, $k = \{1,..., K\}$, $j = \{1,...,J\}$ and $\beta_k(t) $ is element of the below matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_1(1) &\dots & \beta_1(T)\\
\vdots & \ddots   & \vdots\\
\beta_K(1) & \dots & \beta_K(T)
\end{bmatrix}

My query is how to read the term which is present on left part of the curly braces ?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a definition. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: It is the indicator function of the event $\beta_k(t)=j$.

Comment: @ copper.hat, Sir, I had edited the question with more definitions....

Comment: @ Nap D. Lover, Thank you so much sir for your comment....but what does 1 signifies in $1_{\beta_k(t)}(j)$

Comment: 1 is the name of the function. You can read it as "indicator of"

Comment: Ok sir ... Thanks a lot for your response...

Comment: After going through above well explained comments, I googled about Indicator functions and understood it thoroughly ... Thanks to one and all sirs for your supportive answers....